# How can I find out what need to be imported into an android project?

Tags: android, import, dependencies, package

For example: I just added a snippet to show notifications to my project:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
         .setContentTitle("My notification")
         .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

but how can I find out what needs to be imported to avoid errors like: "error: package NotificationCompat does not exist"? Something like "yum whatprovides ..." in fedora linux

Comment: Looks like there is no easy way to get the info that I needed. Installing eclipse just to get it when my main IDE is vim seems to be a serious overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options: Documentation or Eclipse, Eclipse always told you what need import,  for example  when you use a class the first time, you will see:"import XXXXX" and later if you see eclipse doesnt recommend and just doesnt see where. You can go to to documentation in developer.android.com and propably you find a good explication.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommended to use Eclipse. Eclipse automatically show HELP STATEMENTS, and there will be something like : please import : **android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat**
I try NetBeans too but it doesnt help you so much like Eclipse, and for beginner Eclipse is the best way.

Answer (score -1):

Its the support library, which is perfectly safe..  There is nothing like yum what.  As a general rule, if you don't know exactly what code is and where it comes from and you add it to your project, you're an idiot.  Taking random packages from everywhere is just asking for your app to be a massive security hole allowing hackers to take over your user's devices, and it'll look like you're the one doing it when people investigate.

Comment: Ok, that's my first question here, so probably I'm missing something. What do you mean by "random packages"? I did my research befote I asked the question, NotificationCompat is from android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder but importing it changes nothing.

Comment: You asked if you could use a yum-like tool to figure out what packages to include in your app.  Maybe you mis-spoke and meant what to import in an individual file (which is fine to do automatically).  But by what you said it looked like you had found some random code on the internet, included it, and was now asking for what library to download to link with it, which is what yum does (finds packages to download with the requested command).